# Rich text editor iframe insertion problem

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, rich-text-editor

When I adding iframe in rich text editor it's not showing properly in html. This is my editor.
[image]

I'm getting this when trying to show this iframe.
[image]

Did I missed something? Can anyone help me to get?

**This is the view** after adding a iframe I click on on '</>' this.
[image]

Comment: Press the `</>` button and insert there the HTML iframe code and see what happens. if the problem persists, change the double quotes `"` for *single* quotes `'`.

Comment: I added a new picture above.And When I adding after pressing </>  and save my changes. It only taking <p></p> tag. Iframe are disappear.

Comment: See that `<` are changed to `&lt;` - can you add the name of the rich text editor you're using? - I'm not sure if this control is CKEditor...